# When I run flutter devices I don't see my device even if it is connected. I can access my devices with Android Studio but not with CMD or terminals

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I only see Edge and Chrome as devices. But only in Android Studio, I am able to run my apps on any device. I mean I can only see and access my available devices through Android Studio but when I run `flutter devices` in Command Prompt or in VS Code terminal I can't see or access my devices. In the attached image, you can see, that Android studio is detecting my USB device but CMD can't.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me when I was working on a Flutter web project. Your mobile device gets added to the list of available devices, but it cannot run a web project. Connected devices are devices that can run your current web project, i.e.. Chrome and Edge browser.

Comment: so what can I do to fix my current problem?

Comment: @MahirulIslam maybe this coud help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62195515/access-flutter-localhost-from-real-mobile-browser