# How can I host my flutter web app in my local network?

Tags: flutter, web-applications, webserver, hosting

What I need is to run a web app that can only be accessed from my local network.

I built my web app with flutter by typing:

`flutter build web`

but now I'm stuck because I don't know which web server should I use. I searched for tutorial but didn't find a solution.

Comment: Just change you localhost name to your IP address

Comment: What I need is to be able to access it from another device, maybe I badly explained my self, anyway I tried to do that with the command `flutter run -d web-server --web-hostname 0.0.0.0 --web-port 8080` but I can t acces it with another device

Comment: What OS are you using? You need the IP address of your router.

Comment: I'm on windows and I have the router IP

Comment: If you just want to access it from other computers on your local network, you shouldn't need to involve the router.   What is the IP address of your Windows computer on your local network?  You should be able to access the server from other devices using the local IP address of your Windows computer in the URL.

Comment: I have my local network ip, wich is 192.168.2.63 then i used the `flutter run -d web-server --web-hostname 192.168.2.63 --web-port 8080` but if i try to access http://192.168.2.63:8080 from my phone I get `EAR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`. But if i try from my pc I can access it.

Comment: Your phone may not be on your local network then.  Does it work if you turn off mobile data and just have the phone on wifi?   Can if you verify that your phone's IP address is on the same local network (192.168.2.*)?

Comment: Another possibility is that Windows defender firewall is blocking it https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-microsoft-defender-firewall-on-or-off-ec0844f7-aebd-0583-67fe-601ecf5d774f

Comment: pc IP: 192.168.2.63  | phone IP: 192.168.2.109 | router IP: 192.168.2.1 both on PC and phone. I disabled the firewall but i get the same result

Answer (score 1):

The easiest for me was by serving the web build using Python as suggested on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62195693). Once you got Python installed on your machine, navigate to your Flutter project's `build/web/` folder then run `python -m http.server {PORT}`. You can change the port to any free port available in your machine. If you've installed Python 3, the command most likely should start with `python3`.

When the server's running, the Flutter web build can be accessed through a browser with the machine's IP address and the port that you've set i.e. `http://192.168.x.x:8080`