# How can I run and debug my flutter web app on mobile (android/IOS) browser

Tags: android, ios, flutter, debugging, flutter-web

I've just written a feature to redirect user to AppStore/PlayStore if he/she has launched my web app from mobile's browser. My home Screen turns to a white page on some devices and I just don't know how to debug it.
Is there a way to debug my flutter web app on mobile's browser?

Comment: You can run on pc's browser and by using F12 mode and select  ctrl+shift+M for mobile mode. hope that helps you.

Comment: No, That's not solving my problem. The web app is running correctly on windows browsers for any size. But it has UI problems when launching with mobile browsers. I need a way to debug my code while running on mobile's browser.

Comment: Check this if its useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62195515/access-flutter-localhost-from-real-mobile-browser