# flutter on web shows blank page when access https url provided by Ngrok

Tags: flutter, ngrok

i am trying to use Ngrok to access simple flutter app on web via https. local access (http://localhost:8080) shows the page correctly. I can also access Ngrok web interface. however, it shows blank page on https url (url from running ngrok http 8080). it is like the page is loading but it is not complete (the blue progress bar is runnning). do i need to do further set up to make it works? or ngrok does not support flutter web app? thanks

Answer (score 0):

i ran flutter web by using `flutter run -d chrome`. the result is blank page.

to make it works i need to run `flutter build web`
and then run http server

```
cd build/web
python3 -m http.server 8000
```

As used here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66846491/.